# TFS changes overwritten and obliterated from history?

Tags: tfs

It seems like at completely random, someone's changes will disappear, and the history of the changes will disappear as well.  It's almost like the history of a file is tied to the file itself instead of being saved on TFS itself.  Anyone know why this would be happening?

Edit: A little more explanation.

As an example scenario...

I work on item A to reorganize a view and then commit the changes via gated check-in, which finished successfully.

A couple days later, a coworker is working in the same area and turns around and asks me if I was still working on the reorganization because it looks like it has for the past random length of time.  So I step over and look over their shoulder and sure enough, it is EXACTLY as it was before I started working on it.

Naturally, I pull up the history of the file, and there is no record of my commit whatsoever.  It's like I just did the work and commit in my head.

**Final Edit:**
This appeared today - It appears that TFS is taking it upon itself to determine which version is more important and taking that version without consulting the developer.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: can you expand a little, have the changes actually been committed to TFS. are the missing changes in a shelveset?

Comment: Added a sample scenario as to what's going on.

Comment: do your builds still exist? can you see the changeset number from there? are you using TFSVC or GIT

Comment: We're just using TFSVC, and the builds aren't showing either.

Comment: Are you sure the gated checkin is succeeding and commiting your changes? It sounds like the gated checkin build is failing.

Comment: What version of TFS are you using?

Comment: Using TFS 2013 and the checkins are showing to be successful.

Comment: Checkins are a transaction. If they are successful then they are in the history.

Comment: You would think they would be, you would even expect them to be.  But what would cause them to not be registered by TFS?  Because the observed result is that this is not happening 100% of the time.  Even spent several hours trying to force it to happen by butchering the check-in dance steps and couldn't reproduce it.  I only know it DOES happen because I've lost several hours of work myself due to it and a coworker had it happen to them a few days ago.